# See the compilation screen only when it is necessary

Tags: emacs

I have put `(global-set-key "\C-x\C-m" 'compile)` in my `.emacs`. As a result, under `Emacs`, if I use the shortcut `C-x C-m C-m`, 1) I am asked if I want to save the modification; 2) another buffer will be opened under `Emacs` where the compilation is displayed (Additionally, it does not show systematically the end of the compilation, we need to browse down manually).

Is it possible to not let the buffer containing the compilation be disturbing?

Ideally, I want `C-x C-m C-m` to toggle the compilation (I want to save the modification by default). If there is no error, I don't want to see the compilation screen; otherwise, I will find the screen and see the error message.

Does anyone know if it is possible to set this up?

**Edit 1:**

Following the answer of @maxy , I have modified `.emacs` and done some tests. Oddly, there are two cases:

1) If the previous compilation succeeded, another compilation will generate a buffer and then the buffer will NOT be deleted after the compilation:

[image]

2) If the previous compilation did not succeed, after deleting the compilation buffer and correcting the error in the tex file, another compilation will generate a buffer and then the buffer will be deleted after the compilation.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

**Edit 2:**

I've got it. In the answer of @maxy , changing `(run-at-time 0.5 nil 'delete-windows-on buf)` to `(run-at-time 0.5 nil 'delete-other-windows)` will do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem so long ago that I thought it was the emacs default. Sadly it isn't. From my [emacs.el](https://github.com/martinxyz/config/blob/master/elisp/emacs.el):

```
;; get rid of compilation window on success
;; source: http://www.bloomington.in.us/~brutt/emacs-c-dev.html [dead link]
(setq compilation-finish-function
      (lambda (buf str)
        (if (string-match "exited abnormally" str)
            ;;there were errors
            ;(message "compilation errors, press C-x ` to visit")
            (message "ERRORs while compiling.")
          ;;no errors, make the compilation window go away in 0.5 seconds
          (run-at-time 0.5 nil 'delete-windows-on buf)
          (message "Compilation done."))))
```

Also, use `M-x customize-variable` for:

```
 '(compilation-ask-about-save nil)
 '(compilation-context-lines 0)
 '(compilation-scroll-output t)
 '(compilation-window-height 21)
```

In case you are using `swbuff`, see the example for `swbuff-exclude-buffer-regexps` to ignore the `*compilation*` buffer in the list of recently used buffers.

Comment: changing `(run-at-time 0.5 nil 'delete-windows-on buf)` to `(run-at-time 0.5 nil 'delete-other-windows)` will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

From the [EmacsWiki](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeCompile#toc2), put the following in your .emacs:

```
;; If there were no compilation errors, delete the compilation window
(setq compilation-exit-message-function
      (lambda (status code msg)
        ;; If M-x compile exists with a 0
        (when (and (eq status 'exit) (zerop code))
          ;; then bury the *compilation* buffer, so that C-x b doesn't go there
          (bury-buffer "*compilation*")
          ;; and return to whatever were looking at before
          (replace-buffer-in-windows "*compilation*"))
        ;; Always return the anticipated result of compilation-exit-message-function
        (cons msg code)))
```

This actually briefly displays the window but deletes it straight away if there are no errors, restoring whatever window it replaced.

Additionally, you can make Emacs scroll either to the first error or to the end of the compilation buffer like so:

```
(require 'cl)

(setq
 ;; Either
 compilation-scroll-output 'first-error      ;; scroll until first error
 ;; or
 compilation-scroll-output 't                ;; scroll to bottom
)
```

Comment: Thank you... It's better, but if there is no error, it does not delete the compilation buffer.

Comment: Are there warnings? If so, you will also need to add `(setq  compilation-skip-threshold 2) ;; skip warnings`.

Comment: It does delete the compilation messages; the compilation buffer is nonetheless still there, it is filled by another text in the memory or the Emacs welcome page (Welcome to GNU Emacs... Emacs Tutorial... Emacs Guided Tour...). I just would like to delete systematically the created buffer if there is no compilation error.