# Launch make and go to the error position by shortcuts within Emacs

Tags: emacs, makefile

I use Emacs to code. At the moment, to compile an OCaml project, I need to type `make` in a terminal. If there is an error, I have to go back to Emacs to find the erroneous file and location by following the error indication.

Now, I would like to launch `make` inside Emacs by a keyboard shortcut, which opens a buffer to show the compilation, then

1) if there is no error, then close the buffer automatically

2) if there is an error, another shortcut will lead me to the erroneous file and line within Emacs.

Does anyone know how to write `.emacs` to enable this mechanism?

PS: This is my current [.emacs](http://pastebin.com/xGs6bFdG).
I have posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297627/see-the-compilation-screen-only-when-it-is-necessary) to compile one .tex file within Emacs by a shortcut (Ctrl + c + m + m), this works well. But in case of error, I don't ask it to lead me to the error position.

Comment: The way to go is M-x compile, and you have this kind of utility in shell-mode too: `M-x shell` http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M-x compile RET`

See the Emacs manual, node [Compilation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation.html).
And see node [Compilation Mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation-Mode.html) for how to visit error occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Some years back, I had the same question, here's the answer I got on the #emacs irc channel.

```
;; from enberg on #emacs
(setq compilation-finish-function
  (lambda (buf str)
(if (null (string-match ".*exited abnormally.*" str))
    ;;no errors, make the compilation window go away in a few seconds
    (progn
      (run-at-time
       "2 sec" nil 'delete-windows-on
       (get-buffer-create "*compilation*"))
      (message "No Compilation Errors!")))))
;; save the file when I press compile
(setq mode-compile-always-save-buffer-p t)
```